# obtener 1 elemento de un string con expresion regular PHP

Tags: php, regex

tengo este string:

```
$stringe = "123|1|4;124|50|3;12312|231|4324;"
```

literalmente lo construyo asi: id|precio|cantidad;id|precio|cantidad....
lo que deseo obtener es solo los id, es decir los primeros campos despues del ;

de antemano gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Hola. No se entiende del todo. ¿Qué elemento concreto quieres obtener? ¿El `124`?

Comment: usando el ejemplo quisiera obtener 123,124,12312 que son los primeros elementos despues del ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy un experto en expresiones regulares pero podrías utilizar la siguiente: `^\d+|(?<=;)\d+`.

- Con `^`: Obligas a que comience por el siguiente elemento que indiques.
- Con `\d`: Hace match con cualquier elemento que sea un dígito, es decir, cualquier elemento del 0 al 9. Con el `+` hace match si coincide que el elemento anterior, es decir, un dígito, aparezca una o más veces.
- Con `(?<=;)` que afirma que lo que continúa al caracter coincide.
- Con `|` : aplicas alternativas o un OR.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$regex = '/^\d+|(?<=;)\d+/';
$string = '123|1|4;124|50|3;12312|231|4324;';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $output);

var_dump($output);
```

Resultado:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "123"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "124"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "12312"
  }
}
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto amiga, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Me alegro haber sido ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si siempre va a tener la misma estructura ( id|precio|cantidad;id|precio|cantidad ) puedes usar la funcion de php "explode".

Esta función crea un array a partir de una string, separandola mediante el caracter deseado.

Entonces podrias hacer lo siguiente

Usamos explode para separar mediante ";" y obtener un array con cada uno de los productos

```
$stringe = "123|1|4;124|50|3;12312|231|4324;"


$array_productos = explode(";",$stringe);
```

En este punto deberiamos de tener un array con 3 posiciones:

```
[0] "123|1|4"
[1] "124|50|3"
[2] "12312|231|4324"
```

Luego puedes separar cada uno de ellos utilizando de nuevo la función explode pero esta vez usando "|" como el separador. Y asignar al sting resultado ( el string que quieres obtener al final con solo los ids) la primera posición del array devuelto, ya que el id siempre va a ser la primera posición

```
$string_resultado = "";
for($i = 0; $i < count($array_productos); $i++){
    $string_resultado .= explode("|",$array_producto[$i])[0];
    $string_resultado .= ",";
}
```

Aquí al final tendriamos como resultado que la variable string_resultado con el siguiente valor:

```
123,124,12312
```

Comment: si usaba eso amigo, lo que pasa es que son demaciados procesos para algo tan simple, son mas lineas de codigo y mas consumo de memoria, se crean variables temporales inesesarias etc etc, por ello vi que una expresion regular es la mejor opcion, de todas maneras gracias por tu respuesta amigo